# Webkit white space issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, whitespace

Hey guys, getting a error in webkit browsers (chrome/safari) where the padding is being cut off from anchor tags.

Here's an example:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        body 
        {   
            background-color: #F4F4E7;  
            margin: 0;  padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }   
        .restrictedSpace
        {
            margin: 40px;
            width: 300px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            line-height: 28px;
            white-space: normal;
        }
        .restrictedSpace a
        {
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 11px;
            background-position: 7px 7px;
            padding: 5px 7px;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="restrictedSpace">
        <a href="">Here&nbsp;Is&nbsp;A&nbsp;Button</a> <a href="">Here&nbsp;Is&nbsp;A&nbsp;Button</a> <a href="">Here&nbsp;Is&nbsp;A&nbsp;Button</a>  <!-- extra space here--> <a href="">Here&nbsp;Is&nbsp;A&nbsp;Button</a> <a href="">Here&nbsp;Is&nbsp;A&nbsp;Button</a> <a href="">Here&nbsp;Is&nbsp;A&nbsp;Button</a>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You'll notice the third button is getting sliced on the right hand side. This is when I have more than one space in between the two buttons (when reduced to one space, the button doesn't get sliced).

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

I've also done a comparison in each of the major browsers. They all have some different in rendering.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyNGK.jpg

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/4pr58/

Comment: Why would you put an extra space in there anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Your anchor tags are inline. Just like text in a paragraph, inline text will not collapse white space, but respect it. Set your anchors to `display:block;float:left;`, and the white space should disappear.

As to why Webkit decides to render it that way, I'm not sure, but it may be attempting something that generally works with inline text (e.g., if this were just a paragraph with underlined links). (Why Opera does it's own weird thing is again a mystery to me but, well, par for the course for Opera.)

Comment: Floating the anchors is not the best solution.

Comment: @Stu, you certainly don't have to float them if something else fits your design needs, though that's the typical way to achieve that behavior. Just meant as a demonstration of what's going on.

So, to clarify, what's causing that is the browser displaying the anchors as inline text within the div. It's within the norm, even if frustrating--if you want to nix the white space and prevent the anchors from being split up on both lines, you'll need to change that.

Comment: No worries. Just a fair bit annoying for Webkit to handle whitespace in that manner.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must have stumbled upon a bug. Notice if you increase the right padding of the anchor elements, it suddenly snaps wide again at 11px (`padding: 5px 11px 5px 7px`).

You can see it even more clearly if you adjust the right padding of that one anchor only (leaving the others at 7px). It will still slice at 16px, but not at 17px.

I have had the same problem, but never found a solution. I think in the end I just floated the elements.

Comment: That is interesting. For me it snapped to full width on 13px right padding.

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements automatically add 4px of white space to the right of the element, so I'm guessing that when you add the extra space, it adds enough to send the last element out of the containing parent. It's just a guess, but I think that's what happens :)

Comment: There shouldn't be any extra spaces, though. Sequences of whitespace is supposed to collapse, so there should be no difference between 1 and 2.

Comment: Aye that's true.. As I said, it was just a guess. I shall take a closer look :)

Answer (score -1):

The way that I fixed this is:

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Tested in Chrome 29